# What is the standard way to override operator overload behavior in a derived class without manually rewriting and hiding every operator individually?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, crtp

https://godbolt.org/z/n9jEK6xsP

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename Ret = void>
class Base {
 public:
  using CondRet = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<Ret, void>::value, Base, Ret>::type;

  CondRet& operator<<(const char* str) {
    std::cout << str;
    // downcast, youch.
    return *(dynamic_cast<CondRet*>(this));
  }

  // Pretend there are 10-20 more operator<< overloads here.

  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
 public:
  // bring in all the base operators returning our derived type to this scope.
  using Base<Derived>::operator<<;

  // Add operator overloads we would like to support in addition to our base operators.
  Derived& operator<<(int i) {
    std::cout << i;
    return *this;
  }

  ~Derived() override = default;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Base<> myBase;
  // what have I done?
  Derived myDerived;
  myDerived << 3 << " four " << 5;
}
```

Otherwise `" four " << 5;` would not work as the base class wouldn't know about `operator<<(int)` or any other new operator you want to add, for that matter.

Is this an acceptable/standard way to do this? Why doesn't the STL do something like this with, say std::ostringstream?

Comment: For working code, you might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you want to get rid of CRTP?

Comment: @Jarod42 is that what this is called? 
I don't understand your other comment I'm clearly asking about this CRTP you mentioned, and there are none or very little number of posts on it.

Comment: See [Curiously_recurring_template_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) for more details.

Comment: *"I'm clearly asking about this CRTP you mentioned"*. Not so clear, as Victor's answer is unrelated to that.

Comment: I can clear up any questions in that case. I am not looking for a code review for sample code I wrote to ask a question. I am looking for an answer I can use to implement a proper solution within these parameters.

Comment: I struggled searching for a question in SO asking for this, and I found only yours which was unanswered. I suspect there were no answers since your question is a little bit too wordy and the long code example is not really necessary: you could have asked the same in a more generic way without any code snippet. Shortly after finding your question I found other clues to write a solution on my own, so I gave you my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72262082/213871).

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do exactly what you are asking for, allowing to customize the behavior of `operator<<` for any type, even for those where the `operator<<` is already overloaded in `std::ostringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class MyStringStream : public ostringstream
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    inline MyStringStream& operator<<(T const& val)
    {
        (ostringstream&)(*this) << val;
        return *this;
    }

    // This is needed to allow using stream manipulators such as std::endl
    MyStringStream& operator<<(
        ostream& (*pfn)(ostream&))
    {
        pfn(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    // A customized operator<< for double
    MyStringStream& operator<<(double val)
    {
        (void)val;
        (ostringstream&)(*this) << "operator<<(double val)";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyStringStream stream;
    stream << 9.0 << endl;
    cout << stream.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can only suggest you to declare `virtual` the operator in the `Base` class, and if `Derived` does not need to rewrite it, it can be omitted. An object created as `Base` or `Derived` will reuse `Base`'s operator.

```
template <typename Ret>
class Base {
 public:
  virtual Ret& operator<<(const char* str) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Victor, wouldn't this require rewriting the tens of operators manually?